# I cannot Invoke Web Service via Android

Tags: eclipse, web-services, ksoap2, logcat

I have error from logcat:

```
03-19 16:57:28.715: E/dalvikvm(11924): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.project.newproject.MainActivity$1.onClick
03-19 16:57:28.715: W/dalvikvm(11924): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 554 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lcom/project/newproject/MainActivity$1;
03-19 16:57:28.715: D/dalvikvm(11924): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
03-19 16:57:28.715: D/dalvikvm(11924): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0de9 at 0x06 in Lcom/project/newproject/MainActivity$1;.onClick
03-19 16:57:28.715: D/dalvikvm(11924): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0deb at 0x0d in Lcom/project/newproject/MainActivity$1;.onClick
03-19 16:57:28.715: I/dalvikvm(11924): DexOpt: unable to optimize instance field ref 0x034d at 0x11 in Lcom/project/newproject/MainActivity$1;.onClick
03-19 16:57:28.715: D/dalvikvm(11924): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0dee at 0x1a in Lcom/project/newproject/MainActivity$1;.onClick
03-19 16:57:28.790: D/CLIPBOARD(11924): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
03-19 16:57:31.220: D/AndroidRuntime(11924): Shutting down VM
03-19 16:57:31.220: W/dalvikvm(11924): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c2f1f8)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at com.project.newproject.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3591)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
03-19 16:57:31.220: E/AndroidRuntime(11924):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 16:58:54.010: I/Process(11924): Sending signal. PID: 11924 SIG: 9
```

I've tried everything that I know although I couldn't run it correctly. Finally, I've totally copied codes from there for testing my web services; http://mustafa-yildirim.blogspot.com/2010/09/android-net-web-servis-baglants.html and these are my code below.

```
package com.project.newproject;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://mysite/service1.asmx";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button btn_goster = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_goster);
        final EditText edt_goster = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_goster);

        btn_goster.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                AndroidHttpTransport httpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

                SoapPrimitive result = null;
                try {
                    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                    edt_goster.setText(result.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    edt_goster.setText(e.getMessage());
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    edt_goster.setText(e.getMessage());
                }

            }

        });

    }
```

Everything is same and there is no error, but when I run AVD or my phone, there was shown a message called "New Project has stopped". I got it every time :(

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse Rightclick on the project an choose build tools > add external jar file and  select  the ksoap2 jar file.
Also are you sure that you have downloade the version for android( not for j2me and other platforms)? You  should download it from code.google.com

Comment: Thanks 
I have already added form external but it did not work. Then I copied to libs folder then added jar and it's ok. (: